# Software to colorize matching patterns? (like grep, but showing everything, just with matches colored)

Tags: linux, open-source

I am looking for a FLOSS tool for the Linux terminal that acts similar to `grep`, but it should output everything, *not just matching lines*. But the twist is that the matching terms should be colorized (preferably configurable).

In short, I am looking for a `grep --color PATTERN FILE...` on lines with matches and uncolored output for every line without a match.

Doesn't matter if the suggested software is a script or compiled to a binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366/convince-grep-to-output-all-lines-not-just-those-with-matches):

Use `ack` /  `ack-grep`:

```
ack --passthru --color string file
```

or [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```
rg --passthru pattern file.txt
```

You can also achieve the same using `grep`:

```
grep --color -E "test|$" yourfile
```